# Are mu-plugins plugins still deployed via wordpress.org/plugins?

Tags: plugins, mu-plugins

I'm getting ready to publish my first plugin. I've decided to put it in mu-plugin, because if you removed it, it would break other code dependent on it. (It's a developer tool for logging variables to a text file.)

So, do can I submit this to wp.o? Or do they only accept plugins that go into the plugins directory?

Comment: I believe just the plugins directory, but you could email them and ask, they might have suggestions too, plugins@wordpress.org.  And there's always github.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, mu-plugins cannot be updated from wordpress.org. When you submit a plugin to that repository, it will be available as a regular plugin only. You can ask your users to isntall it as a mu-plugin, but they will not receive updates then.

The “other code” should be written in a way that it doesn’t do *anything* when your plugin is disabled. This is much better than using the mu-plugins directory.